# Batch delete system files that are protected by the system

Tags: batch-file, windows-8.1

I recently installed a virus, and after taking care of that, it had installed multitudes of files in every folder on my computer. I managed to delete all of them using `del` except that there are some files that are protected. I navigated to the folder they are in (C:\Users\Public\AccountPictures\Big_folder_name)and tried to manually delete them. The problem, is that I can't change the permissions of the item. I have tried everything I could find online, but could not find anything pertaining to this issue.
My code is very simple. Is there any way to change it so that it would delete those files as well? If not, is there a way to delete those files manually?

Code:

```
del /s /f C:\*HELP_FILE_*
pause
```

Edit: ICACLS pointed out that Everyone had(OI)(CI)(R), however through Windows Explorer, I still can't change that permission.
In the permission entry, all the boxes are grey and I can't change anything. I would post an image, but the file size limit is too small.

Answer:
I somewhat solved my problem. I found the application [Unlocker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml). It was slow and rather time consuming, not what I was looking for, but it worked. If you know the code to do this, please still post an answer, as it may help others with the same problem.

Comment: Type `icacls "c:\folder\filename.ext"`. Also `openfiles /local on`, reboot, then `openfiles /query /v`. Post the relevant output.

Comment: I used `icacls "C:\Users\Public\AccountPictures\Big_folder_name" /grant Daniel:(OI)(CI)F` but the command prompt just says Access is denied. I have ran it as an Administrator.

Comment: I want to see the permissions. Just run it as I said. Edit info gathered into your question.

Comment: Now do `Openfiles`. Access Denied has many causes. Although above only gives Everyone permission to read. Try `takeown /f "c:\etc\file.ext" /a`. Then give yourself permission. If openfiles show nothing then use Process Explorer to search for the file https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx.